# Store Omniauth auth data between requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

1. A user is logged in with traditional email and password.
2. That user clicks a "connect with Facebook" button.
3. They auth with facebook using a **different** email address than the one they're currently logged in to my site with.
4. I present them with a page asking if they want to update their traditional login to use their facebook email (also allowing me to unify the accounts and fill in any missing data using Facebook).

The problem is with step 4, as the omniauth callback URL hits `sessions#create` with the auth stored in `request.env['omniauth.auth']`.

Relevant bits of `sessions_controller`:

```
def create
  return link_accounts if signed_in?

  if params[:email]
    create_session_from_login
  elsif env['omniauth.auth']
    create_session_from_facebook
  else
    redirect_to login_path, alert: "Couldn't login!"
  end
end 

private

def link_accounts
  auth = env['omniauth.auth']
  redirect_to user_link_accounts_path current_user unless current_user.email == auth[:info][:email]
end
```

... which takes me to my user controller, which displays a lovely little message prompting the user to either (a) sign into my site as another user, or (b) update their account to use this Facebook info... except that I no longer have access to `request.env['omniauth.auth']`.

How can I persist the auth info between requests? It's too big for `session`... I also want it someplace I can get to it after a user takes an action on a page (as in, clicking a link--so I can auth them server-side one request after the actual FB auth has taken place), but I don't want to store it on the page...